# How to fork interactive programs

Tags: unix, shared-memory, mmap, pty

I have an *interactive* program with a high start-up cost. After start-up, I'd like to fork the process into separate concurrent sessions. Ideally each separate session would become a [GNU screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) window but being able to individually telnet/ssh to each session would be fine too.

It shouldn't be too hard to write this from scratch but it seems like something that should have been done/considered before and maybe there are reasons why this is a bad idea...

I know that an alternative approach is to use shared memory for the data that's expensive to initialize. The reason I'm reluctant to go down that path is that the shared data uses C++ data structures with pointers, which makes it hard to mmap it into an unrelated process.

Comment: Update: I coded up a proof of concept of a Python library that starts a Unix domain socket listener and on each client connect forks the Python program, passing the pty master fd via the socket to the client; I also wrote a small C client that then connects the pty master fd to the controlling tty of the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is what any database does - the startup is phenomenally expensive, but the db provides several different means of connecting - example Oracle's BEQ protocol.

Telnet has issues, consider ssh.  Either way, consider a daemon that answers requests for connect on  a port (you would use AF_UNIX sockets I guess), then creates a separate session.

Stevens Advanced Programming in the UNIX Envrionment or Rochkind's Advanced UNIX Programming have discussions and complete examples.  Since my Stevens book seems to have gone on extensive holiday, see Rochkind 4.3 and 4.10.

And no, there is no pending doom for using this approach.